# Square of Opposition - Contradictories

Tags: logic

I am having a hard time understanding the Square of Opposition Concept.

For contradictories, we must have that they both cannot be false and they both cannot be true. Say I have the propositons,

A = All lawyers are judges

O = Some lawyers are not judges

$\implies $A false = Some lawyers are judges/No lawyers are judges.

$\implies $ O false = Some lawyers are judges

So A and O can be false together in one case, but still they are said to be contradictory. Why is that?

**EDIT:** Could you help me with the false part of each A, E, I and O? I think not knowing the exact false of each is causing problems in my analysis of Square of Opposition terms.

Answer (score 1):

Your negation of O is incorrect. If "some lawyers are not judges" is false, then all lawyers are judges. (It is possible for some people to be judges and some not, so they are not negations of one another.)

Perhaps it is more enlightening to write it out, namely, in more formal phrasing, we have that your O is

There exist a lawyer which is not a judge.

So if no such lawyer exists, then all lawyers are judges.

Comment: But I could also begin with "There exists a lawyer which is a judge" right? Though this is not true every time, it is true sometimes at least.

Comment: Also, all lawyers are judges is compatible with Some Lawyers are judges (A false)

Comment: The problem is that "There exists a lawyer which is a judge" is not the negation of "There exists a lawyer which is not a judge."

Comment: How do you figure out the right negation?

Comment: https://www.math.toronto.edu/preparing-for-calculus/3_logic/we_3_negation.html; there is a section on "for all" and "there exist" statements